# Two reversed conditions in one onAfterDispatch() plugin function

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, joomla-api

In my system plugin, I use the following condition

```
class PlgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onAfterDispatch()
    {
        $uri = JFactory::getURI();
        $current_url = $uri->toString();
        if(strpos($current_url,'?mykey') === false) {
            return true;
        }
    // some event that is being executed when url HAS ?mykey
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. But I need one more event that will be executed under reversed condition i.e. when url has no ?mykey

I try

```
class PlgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onAfterDispatch()
    {
        $uri = JFactory::getURI();
        $current_url = $uri->toString();
        if(strpos($current_url,'?mykey') === false) {
            return true;
        }
        // some event that is being executed when url HAS ?mykey

        if(strpos($current_url,'?mykey') !== false) {
            return true;
        }
        // some event that is being executed when url HAS NO ?mykey
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work and it looks like an incorrect statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the URL can either **have** or **not have** `?mykey`, surely you can use an `else` condition can't you?

Like so:

```
if(strpos($current_url,'?mykey') !== false) 
{
    // URL has ?mykey

    // Do some fancy code here

    // You've finished what you need to do, so stop anything else
    return true;
}
else
{
    // URL doesn't have ?mykey

    // Do some fancy code here

    // You've finished what you need to do, so stop anything else
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about it. But if you'll look in Joomla loadposition plugin (lines about 32-34) there is _reversed_ condition the events are being executed under. I can't understand why, maybe because of `return true`. I'm new in PHP and don't know what it means but in plugin(s) for some reason it works under _reversed_ condition

Comment: @stckvrw - the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function. So if you're using it before you need to process any code, it won't work. I've update my answer for you